# What's the least amount of ether that can be sent in a transaction? Can you send 0 ether?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-design, gas

What's the least amount of ether that can be sent in a transaction? Would it be 0.000000000000000001? Or can you send 0 ether? How would you do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can **send** zero Ethereum in a transaction (in fact, many of the function calls you make on smart contracts will have you sending zero Ethereum), but you aren't currently able to **spend** zero Ethereum when you send a transaction. At the very least, you will have to **spend** the cost of gas to pay for the transaction's processing.

The **send** is specified in the `value` or `amount` field of a transaction. Your Ethereum wallet will allow you to enter this amount if the smart contract requires it, or if you are sending ether to another person. The `value` can be zero, for example, if you are simply sending your friend a message in the `input` field. But you would get charged `gas` which you can think of as a transaction fee. The wallet will extract the gas and send it along by default.

Hope that helps.